# macOS not allowing to change the sequence of partitions from command line!

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

This is the Disk List for my iMac.

[image]

I am trying to merge the partitions macOS and macOS 2 using diskutil mergePartitions now the problem is on running this command macOS will keep data on the first partition which is macOS and will erase everything in between the first and last partition (Last partition included), now the last partition is macOS 2.

I want to preserve the last partition which is macOS 2 and delete every other partition so I thought why not include the last partition as the first partition (Which I want to preserve the data on) and include the first partition in the last parameter - which will be deleted.

Here's where the issue occurs macOS doesn't allows me to change the sequence of the partition

So I am stuck with merging partitions from command line

I don't want to use disk utility to merge partitions cause last time when I used it to merge partitions some free spaces were created and were not going away until and unless an entire disk format was performed!

One more thing macOS is the first volume on the disk so removing it from dusk utility using the partition option will not happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expand disk0s4 to lower blocks numbers with on-board tools! To "expand" disk0s4 you would have to remove disk0s2 , add a new partition with the same size and type as disk0s4 directly following disk0s1 all with `gpt`, `dd` disk0s4 to disk0s2, delete disk0s3 and disk0s4 with `gpt` and finally expand disk0s2 with `diskutil` into the unallocated space between disk0s2 and disk0s5.

Instead of the last two steps you can also use the `diskutil mergePartitions ...` command.

All that booted either in Internet Recovery Mode or an external drive with macOS installed.

---

- Boot to Internet Recovery Mode or an external boot drive (if you aren't superuser you have to prepend `sudo` to `gpt ...` and `dd ...` commands.
- Get an overview and check disk and volumes (repair if necessary) :

  ```
  diskutil verifyDisk disk0
  diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2
  diskutil verifyVolume disk0s4
  diskutil list
  gpt -r show disk0
  ```
- Remove disk0s2:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  gpt remove -i 2 disk0
  ```
- add a partition with the same size as disk0s3

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 485642672 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
  ```
- copy disk0s4 to disk0s2:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  dd if=/dev/disk0s4 of=/dev/disk0s2 bs=4m
  ```
- merge disk0s2-disk0s4 and rename *macOS 2* to *macOS*:

  ```
  diskutil mergePartitions HFS+ "macOS" disk0s2 disk0s4
  ```

Comment: I will paste the output of the gpt command in order to understand the steps better. I am confused and I don't want to delete anything in confusion!

Comment: Please paste it as **text** (not as screenshot)!

Comment: Here's the output https://pastebin.com/ud17Ribf

Comment: After all the merging when I booted into the OS I am being greeted with a groups icon and a blank username and password dialogue box I don't know what to input!

Comment: Your old user name and password from macOS 2?!

Comment: Both my partitions had macOS with root user enabled! Both had different usernames and passwords, I am typing in both passwords and usernames and nothing is being accepted!

Comment: Then "root" and your root password

Comment: I am typing in that but macOS is not accepting that and I don't see the default Avatar I had for my username instead of that there is a groups and users icon

Comment: Root got accepted!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69827/discussion-between-klanomath-and-sayan).

Comment: But I don't see my files and all my custom settings has been reverted to deafult settings!

Answer (score 3):

Since the volumes are about the same size, you can use the Disk Utility application to "Restore" the `macOS` volume from the `macOS 2` volume. You basically will then have duplicated `macOS 2`. You then can delete `disk0s4` and expand `disk0s2` to recover the free space.

All these operations can be performed using the Disk Utility application.

If you are wish to use the command line, then here is the command to clone the volume labeled "macOS 2".

```
sudo asr restore --source "/Volumes/macOS 2" --target /Volumes/macOS --erase
```

> Note: The above command also clones `/dev/disk0s5` to `/dev/disk0s3`.

The command to delete `/dev/disk0s4` and expand `/dev/disk0s2` is given below.

```
diskutil mergePartitions FREE "" disk0s2 disk0s4
```

> Note: The above command also deletes `/dev/disk0s5` and relocates `/dev/disk0s3` to be below the expanded `/dev/disk0s2`.

The clone/restore operation could be done while booted from `/dev/disk0s5`. The merge operation could be done while booted to `/dev/disk0s2`.

Comment: I would very much like to know how to do this from within Disk Utility itself.  I don't see any obvious way beyond creating a disk image of the second volume and restoring it to the first.

Comment: Never mind, once I booted in recovery mode I see that you can restore to one partition directly from another. Very cool!